# Deleting events published by AWS S3 buckets which are still in queue to be processed by lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My architecture is:

1.Drop multiple files in aws S# bucket
2. Lambda picks the file one by one and starts processing it

Problem is :
    I am not able to stop the lambda to process the files in between. Even if i stop the lambda instance and restart it, it picks from where it left.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the events pushed by S3. You'll be better off if you just cancel the Lambda subscription if you want to stop it for good, but I am afraid that already emitted events will be processed as long as your Lambda is active.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

If you want to limit the number of files your Lambda functions can process, you can just limit of concurrent executions on your function to 1, so it won't auto-scale based on demand.

Simply go to Concurrency as the image below shows, set it to 1 and save it.

[image]

Comment: I dropped thousands of files in S3 and they are being executed from last couple of days by lambda. Problem is no new file will  be picked by lambda until it processes all of them. I have deleted all the old files from S3 but events are already published. is there a way to clear those events?

Comment: Or is there a way we could set the limit on life of S3 events which are going to be published?

Comment: Unfortunately there’s no way to achieve it. If you just want it to stop now, why not delete your function and start over?

Comment: But it’s weird that lambda has been processing these files for days. Are you sure you’re not putting the processed objects back to the same bucket therefore triggering an infinite loop?

Comment: One last resort if you don’t want to go with the above would be to contact AWS and see whether they can remove these events for you.

Answer (score 0):

Detach the lambda S3 trigger and add it newly.

This way all new events will be picked up and not the old events

Comment: Isn't LATEST and TRIM_HORIZON for Kinesis only? I've never seen such things on S3.

Comment: you are right. Those are for Kinesis and DynamoDB streams. Edited the post